# Get nested ressources when using cakePhp restfull

Tags: rest, cakephp

I'm using cakePhp to create a Rest api (see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/fr/development/rest.html) and I need to get nested resources. The documentation tells how to get let's say books implementing a URI /books.json. But does not tell how to get for example reviews for a given book. What I'm trying to make is somthing like this: /books/14/reviews.json that returns Review resources.

Can any one tell me hwo to make this?

Comment: Please always mention the exact CakePHP version you are using!

Comment: Hi, I use the latest 2.4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [**Custom REST Routing**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html#custom-rest-routing) section of the docs you've linked. In case the default routing doesn't work for you, you'll have to create your own custom routes that either replace or extend the default ones.

Your `/books/14/reviews.json` URL could for example be mapped to `BooksController::reviews()` likes this:

```
Router::connect(
    '/books/:id/reviews',
    array(
        '[method]' => 'GET',
        'controller' => 'books',
        'action' => 'reviews'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => Router::ID . '|' . Router::UUID,
        'pass' => array(
            'id'
        )
    )
);
```

When placed *before* `Router::mapResources()` it should work fine together with the default routes.

Comment: That worked, thanks for your answer it was right to the point.